# How to make Navigation Bar translucent on specific view?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a drill down hierarchy of three views, all embedded in a Navigation Controller. I want the last view to have the navigation bar translucent, but on return to the previous two first views the Navigation Bar not translucent. I have tried implementing the `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true;` code in the views `viewDidLoad` func but no avail, it just remains the same. What should i implement?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I am miss understanding this but you want to make the translucent bar disappear again and become hidden? If thats the case then you should set the bar back to hidden in the ViewWillDisappear()

That should solve your problem!

Comment: no, i have three table views, all in a drill down succession. I want the first two views to have a regular navigation bar, but the last views navigation bar to be translucent.

Comment: then instead of having the nav bar be hidden have translucent = false when you go back aka viewwilldisappear()

Comment: the thing is, i van not get the bar to become translucent at all, that was the problem i described in the question

Answer (score 0):

In the last view

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false 
}
```

Comment: its not working, i might add i do have a custom image as the navigation bars background, would that make a difference?

Answer (score -1):

You may try this method in your program.
Remember to execute this method in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method.
If you're NOT using a navigation controller in your program, you're gonna replace `self.navigationController` with your own navigationBar.

```
- (void)navigationBarInitializationWithTransparentOption:(BOOL)isAffirmative
{
    //An optional statement below, just to make sure the navigationBar is in its place:
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;//(or separate ".navigationBarHidden" to ".navigationBar.hidden")
    //
    //TO MAKE THE BACKGROUND OF THE CURRENT NAVIGATION BAR TRANSLUCENT:
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:isAffirmative];
    //set NO in the following statement will leave the border of the navigation bar visible
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```